# GitHub git log to log commit count for specific file

Tags: github, git-log

I've been messing around with the following:
https://gist.github.com/sg-s/2ddd0fe91f6037ffb1bce28be0e74d4e

I've been trying to edit to to log the commit count for a specific file, however I'm at a loss.

This is where I'm at, but it doesn't work - somehow it's still for the entire repo, and somehow it's no longer for commit count, but for some other weird number.

`git log main -- myluafile.lua pretty=oneline | wc -l > build_number` took the count from 1391 to 1397.
I would expect it to reflect the actual commit count of the file, adding +1 for each commit I make.

What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 0):

`git log --oneline snoogens-retail.lua | wc -l > build_number` this works! :)